# Can't compile and link grpc to c++ program

Tags: c++, makefile, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a file that uses gRPC and protocol buffers. When I try to compile it though, I get the following error:

```
g++ -std=c++11 `pkg-config --cflags protobuf grpc` keyvaluestore.pb.cc -I /usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib `pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++ grpc` -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgrpc++_reflection -Wl,--as-needed -ldl -lz -c -o keyvaluestore.pb.o
g++ -std=c++11 `pkg-config --cflags protobuf grpc` keyvaluestore.grpc.pb.cc -I /usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib `pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++ grpc` -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgrpc++_reflection -Wl,--as-needed -ldl -lz -c -o keyvaluestore.grpc.pb.o
g++ -std=c++11 `pkg-config --cflags protobuf grpc` backend_server.cc -I /usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib `pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++ grpc` -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgrpc++_reflection -Wl,--as-needed -ldl -lz -c -o backend_server.o
g++ -std=c++11 `pkg-config --cflags protobuf grpc` keyvaluestore.pb.o keyvaluestore.grpc.pb.o backend_server.o -I /usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib `pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++ grpc` -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgrpc++_reflection -Wl,--as-needed -ldl -lz -o backend_server
/usr/bin/ld: keyvaluestore.pb.o: in function `google::protobuf::Arena::AllocHook(std::type_info const*, unsigned long) const':
keyvaluestore.pb.cc:(.text._ZNK6google8protobuf5Arena9AllocHookEPKSt9type_infom[_ZNK6google8protobuf5Arena9AllocHookEPKSt9type_infom]+0x41): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Arena::OnArenaAllocation(std::type_info const*, unsigned long) const'
/usr/bin/ld: keyvaluestore.pb.o: in function `google::protobuf::internal::GetEmptyStringAlreadyInited[abi:cxx11]()':
keyvaluestore.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal27GetEmptyStringAlreadyInitedB5cxx11Ev[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal27GetEmptyStringAlreadyInitedB5cxx11Ev]+0xb): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::fixed_address_empty_string[abi:cxx11]'
/usr/bin/ld: keyvaluestore.pb.o: in function `google::protobuf::internal::EpsCopyInputStream::DoneWithCheck(char const**, int)':
keyvaluestore.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal18EpsCopyInputStream13DoneWithCheckEPPKci[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal18EpsCopyInputStream13DoneWithCheckEPPKci]+0xf0): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::EpsCopyInputStream::DoneFallback(char const*, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:32: backend_server] Error 1
```

I'm quite certain that I have all the packages installed:

```
sudo apt install -y build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config
```

And grpc was installed in `/usr/local`

Makefile:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
CPPFLAGS += `pkg-config --cflags protobuf grpc`

LDFLAGS += -I /usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib `pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++ grpc`\
        -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgrpc++_reflection -Wl,--as-needed\
        -ldl\
                -lz

PROTOC = protoc
GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN = grpc_cpp_plugin
GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_PATH ?= `which $(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN)`
PROTOS_PATH= ../protos

vpath %.proto $(PROTOS_PATH)

%.o: %.cc
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -c -o $@

backend_server: keyvaluestore.pb.o keyvaluestore.grpc.pb.o backend_server.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

%.grpc.pb.cc: %.proto
    $(PROTOC) -I $(PROTOS_PATH) --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=$(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_PATH) $<

%.pb.cc: %.proto
    $(PROTOC) -I $(PROTOS_PATH) --cpp_out=. $<
```

backend_server.cc:

```
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include "../protos/keyvaluestore.grpc.pb.h"

using namespace std;
using grpc::Server;
using grpc::ServerBuilder;
using grpc::ServerContext;
using grpc::Status;
using keyvaluestore::KeyValueStore;
using keyvaluestore::Request;
using keyvaluestore::Response;

unordered_map<string, unordered_map<string, string>> TABLET;

class KeyValueStoreServiceImpl final : public KeyValueStore::Service {
    Status Get(ServerContext* context, const Request* req, Response* res) override {
      auto uit = TABLET.find(req->user());
      if (uit == TABLET.end()) {
         // User not found 
      } else {
          auto cit = TABLET.find(req->key());
          if (cit == TABLET.end()) {
              // Column not found
          } else {
              // Column found
              res->set_val(TABLET[req->user()][req->key()]);
          }
      }
      return Status::OK;
    }

    Status Put(ServerContext* context, const Request* req, Response* res) override {
       auto uit = TABLET.find(req->user());
       if (uit == TABLET.end()) {
          // User not fonud
       } else {
          TABLET[req->user()].insert({ req->key(), req->val() });
       }
       return Status::OK;
    }
};

void RunServer() {
  std::string server_address("127.0.0.1:5000");
  KeyValueStoreServiceImpl service;

  ServerBuilder builder;
  // Listen on the given address without any authentication mechanism.
  builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
  // Register "service" as the instance through which we'll communicate with
  // clients. In this case, it corresponds to an *synchronous* service.
  builder.RegisterService(&service);
  // Finally assemble the server.
  std::unique_ptr<Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());
  std::cout << "Server listening on " << server_address << std::endl;

  // Wait for the server to shutdown. Note that some other thread must be
  // responsible for shutting down the server for this call to ever return.
  server->Wait();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  RunServer();

  return 0;
}
```

`pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++ grpc` outputs:

```
-L/usr/local/lib -lprotobuf -lpthread -lgrpc++ -labsl_raw_hash_set -labsl_hashtablez_sampler -labsl_exponential_biased -labsl_hash -labsl_bad_variant_access -labsl_city -labsl_status -labsl_cord -labsl_bad_optional_access -labsl_str_format_internal -labsl_synchronization -labsl_graphcycles_internal -labsl_symbolize -labsl_demangle_internal -labsl_stacktrace -labsl_debugging_internal -labsl_malloc_internal -labsl_time -labsl_time_zone -labsl_civil_time -labsl_strings -labsl_strings_internal -labsl_throw_delegate -labsl_int128 -labsl_base -labsl_spinlock_wait -labsl_raw_logging_internal -labsl_log_severity -labsl_dynamic_annotations -lgrpc -laddress_sorting -lre2 -lupb -lcares -lz -labsl_raw_hash_set -labsl_hashtablez_sampler -labsl_exponential_biased -labsl_hash -labsl_bad_variant_access -labsl_city -labsl_status -labsl_cord -labsl_bad_optional_access -labsl_str_format_internal -labsl_synchronization -labsl_graphcycles_internal -labsl_symbolize -labsl_demangle_internal -labsl_stacktrace -labsl_debugging_internal -labsl_malloc_internal -labsl_time -labsl_time_zone -labsl_civil_time -labsl_strings -labsl_strings_internal -labsl_throw_delegate -labsl_int128 -labsl_base -labsl_spinlock_wait -labsl_raw_logging_internal -labsl_log_severity -labsl_dynamic_annotations -lgpr -labsl_str_format_internal -labsl_synchronization -labsl_graphcycles_internal -labsl_symbolize -labsl_demangle_internal -labsl_stacktrace -labsl_debugging_internal -labsl_malloc_internal -labsl_time -labsl_time_zone -labsl_civil_time -labsl_strings -labsl_strings_internal -labsl_throw_delegate -labsl_int128 -labsl_base -labsl_spinlock_wait -labsl_raw_logging_internal -labsl_log_severity -labsl_dynamic_annotations -lssl -lcrypto
```

Comment: Don't you need to compile the generated keyvaluestore.grpc.pb.cc as well? You should probably also compile your code with `-std=c++11` instead of relying on the compiler default.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I updated my makefile and the error message; it's still giving me an undefined reference though.

Comment: Also need to add `-std=c++11` to `CXXFLAGS` so object files get compiled with that. Also show us what `pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++ grpc` actually outputs.

Comment: Also make sure that the version of `protoc` used matches the version of the protobuf library you're linking with.

Comment: Just added edit to my post to show what `pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++ grpc` outputs

Comment: Just edited my up to date makefile with CXXFLAGS. How do I check version of my protobuf library?

Comment: Your compilation line does not match your `%.o: %.cc` rule. Either the output does not correspond to the `Makefile` or the rule is not considered for whatever reason and built-in rule takes place instead. Either way the compilation line does not include cflags from `pkg-config`, so the includes probably do not match the library.

Comment: I tried adding `$(CPPFLAGS)` to my make rules. It still doesn't work.. could you show me how please? I'm kind of lost and quite new to make and compiling c++ files.

Comment: I also updated the error message, perhaps now it shows better the compilation output.